# Intersect of two tables fails in SAP ABAP CDS

Tags: abap, opensql

I want to check if two columns of two tables are indeed related.
For which I am using a simple INTERSECT between two columns of different tables that I know are related.
If a match in data is found, that would mean data from one table is present in the other.

```
select customid from sbook
INTERSECT
select id from scustom
```

However, this results in an error> Query Execution failed UP TO n ROWS currently cannot be used in INTERSECT

How to get this going?

Comment: These 3 lines of ABAP code don't compile: please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also make sure that your ABAP version is 7.57 or above (due to [`INTERSECT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_757_index_htm/7.57/en-US/index.htm?file=abapunion.htm)).

Answer (score 1):

ABAP open SQL statement **UP TO n ROWS** gets converted to **LIMIT n** in native SQL.

Please note that DDL SQL of CDS views has limitations and it doesnt support neither 'UP TO n ROWS' nor TOP/LIMIT statements.

**Option 1:** Is to implement CDS table function which uses HANA Native SQL and has support for TOP/LIMIT statements. Sample code is as below.

```
define table function zmsk_intersect_tabfunc 
returns {
   mandt: abap.clnt;
   customid   : s_customer;  
}
implemented by method zmsk_intersect_tabfnc=>get_data;

CLASS zmsk_intersect_tabfnc DEFINITION
  PUBLIC FINAL CREATE PUBLIC .

  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_amdp_marker_hdb .
    CLASS-METHODS get_data.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS zmsk_intersect_tabfnc IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD get_data BY DATABASE PROCEDURE FOR HDB LANGUAGE
  SQLSCRIPT USING sbook scustom.

*    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (
    SELECT customid  AS cust FROM sbook
    INTERSECT
    SELECT id AS cust FROM scustom
    LIMIT 10 --Comment this line when TOP is used
*    )
     ;
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

**Option 2:** If the CDS view is accessed from ABAP code, you can add UP TO n ROWS to the select statement in ABAP.